# GitHub push issue - displaying invalid password

Tags: git, github, passwords, git-commit, git-push

I am unable to push my commit to github, it's saying invalid username or password

Click on the interface below to see the code

[The interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtESe.png)

Comment: Please paste text as a code block instead of posting images of text.  Images aren't searchable and nor accessible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you've just shown us all your token, so you should immediately rotate or regenerate it so that you don't get your account compromised.

Part of the reason this is occurring is that your token is in the URL, and that's not a good place for it.  That stores it in plaintext on the system and, because it's in the URL and the username, it's visible anytime the URL is printed.

What's better is to change the URL with `git remote set-url origin URL-WITHOUT-TOKEN` and then, when prompted to enter a username and password in text mode, enter your username, and your personal access token.  Note that you shouldn't actually use your password and that your token won't be echoed, so you'll probably just want to paste the token and type Enter.  Assuming you're using a credential manager, which is the default on Windows, that will save your credentials for further use.

However, because you're on Windows, you may be using Git Credential Manager Core.  If so, you may see a graphical pop-up like [as in this blog post](https://github.blog/2020-07-02-git-credential-manager-core-building-a-universal-authentication-experience/) which will generate and store a token for you.  In such a case, you *do* want to use your real password, since you're essentially logging into GitHub, and then it will generate and store the token for you for the future.